# MySQL sysobjects counting

Tags: mysql, count, procedure

I am new to mysql and have a task to count total amount of objects that was returned from sysobject function. And its must be user saved procedure.

Basically i know how to do it separate but cant think how to make it in 1 single procedure.

```
select * from sysobjects  where xtype IN('V','U','TR','C')
```

This will take fields that i need from

```
select count(*) from sysobjects where xtype='v' group by xtype
```

and this can calculate only summ of V elements, but i need to calculate total summ
And get this all into single procedure..
Can anyone help me?

And if forgot to mention that it would be nice to print summ to 'message'`s though print function... ;(

Answer (score 0):

I think this should give you the total count:

```
    select count(*) as total_count from sysobjects 
    where xtype IN('V','U','TR','C')
```

If I am missing something then try using a nested subquery as below:

```
    select sum(count) from
     (select count(*) as count from sysobjects 
       where xtype IN('V','U','TR','C') group by xtype
     );
```

The inner query gives you the group wise count and outer query gives you the sum of all of them.

Comment: Woah. just added last piece 'as summ' and it worked magically!

Comment: I think the group by is innecesary

Comment: Yea. Works without it. Btw, why AS Result doesnt name my column Result and shows like (NO COLUMN NAME) ?

Comment: No. i need to output it via 'print' function. Just asking by why "AS RESULT" didnt named my column 'result'

Comment: Maybe my bad somewhere! Thank for helping me! How can i combine result from mine 1st code piece and your 1st(it works great!)? And how can i transfer count into variable?

Comment: Yes. I thought about inner join, but have no idea about realising it ;(

Comment: Not quite that... i need whole information from select * from sysobjects  where xtype IN('V','U','TR','C') PLUS select count(*) as total_count from sysobjects  where xtype IN('V','U','TR','C') in 1 query...

Comment: Incorrect syntax error near the keyword WHERE. Near the 'as temp' ;(

Comment: @user1899717 I misplaced `as TEMP`. Try corrected query as above and if still it gives error, simply remove it (as TEMP) as that is just for readability. It should work without it.

Comment: Same error at where a.xtype:( Final means you wont help me anymore ?Yet i am really grateful to you. God bless you!

Comment: @user1899717 I got sad because it's not working for you. Try this: `select a.*, (select count(*) from sysobjects as b where b.xtype IN ('V','U','TR','C')) as total_count from sysobjects as a where a.xtype IN ('V','U','TR','C')`. If doesn't work, share me the error message.

Comment: Now it works! Nearly perfect! Where should i put 'as' to name that column ? And how can i transfer result from that column into variable to make 'print' function ? :) Sorry for being so annoying and asking so many questions :(

Comment: @user1899717 I already put the `alias` (`as total_count`). Choose the naming as per your need. By variablei, you mean PHP variable and MySQL variable. Also, do you want to print the count only and each of the columns?

Comment: @user1899717 If PHP, you would want something like `$result = mysql_query("SELECT......");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['colName1'] . " " .$row['colName2']." ".$row['total_count'];
  echo "<br />";
  }`

Comment: It isnt named total_count - current name is (No column name). About variable i mean something like this but for your function. DECLARE @o VARCHAR SET @o=(Select count(*) as total_count from sysobjects where xtype IN ('v','u','TR','C') PRINT 'TOTAL NUMBER:'+@o

Comment: @user1899717 You mean: `select a.*, @TOTAL NUMBER:=(select count(*) from sysobjects as b where b.xtype IN ('V','U','TR','C')) from sysobjects as a where a.xtype IN ('V','U','TR','C')`. You can now use `@TOTAL NUMBER` in the print.

Comment: A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations. :( I am going to go offline for a few hours. Big thanks for all your help. If you can - please try to find a solution.